# ORA-01900: LOGFILE keyword expected when trying to drop tablespace

Tags: oracle, database-administration

```
SQL> alter database drop tablespace XXX including contents and datafiles;
alter database drop tablespace XXX including contents and datafiles
                    *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01900: LOGFILE keyword expected
```

Note : I do not have datafile regarding this tablespace I have deleted it manually.

Please advice me and also if any article regarding backup tablespaces please share

Comment: Where [in the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_1006.htm#SQLRF00802) did you find that syntax?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be mixing up syntax from different commands. [`drop tablespace` is a standalone statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9004.htm):

[image]

The [`alter database` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_1004.htm#SQLRF00802) is separate; it has a `drop logfile` clause, but not `drop tablespace`. The parser is seeing the `drop ...` in your statement and is expecting the next word to therefore be `logfile` - and since it isn't, it generates the error you see.

So you only need to do:

```
drop tablespace XXX including contents and datafiles;
```

(assuming you're really sure you do want to get rid of it permenantly, of course!)